# Use sql queries in Laravel 6 to count the number of workers in each department

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm new in laravel and sql. I have two models (Worker and Department) and each model has one to many relationships. Each model has db tables workers and departments. My questions are:

1. Can we use sql query in laravel 6 to count number of workers in each department?
2. where we can use this sql query inside controller or model?

I used this query inside controller but gives me error, what is wrong with it?

```
public function count()
{
   SELECT COUNT(id), department FROM Worker GROUP BY department; 
}
```

Comment: share your models relationship, also share what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Department` Model:

```
class Department extends Model
{

    public function workers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Worker');
    }

}
```

So, you count how many workers are in each department like this:

```
$departments = App\Department::withCount('workers')->get();
```

---

See also:

[Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

[Laravel best practices](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices)

Comment: @RayannNarayan can we use count() instead of withCount().

Answer (score 0):

To use raw query in Laravel controller, you must combine it in query builder. This will work:

```
DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(id), department FROM Worker GROUP BY department");
```